# Failure to find com.google.code.guice:guice:jar:2.0 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

Tags: eclipse, maven

Could not find com.google.code.guice:guice:jar:2.0.

I added this as a dependency in pom still it does not get downloaded.

```
INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building JIRAService 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.code.guice:guice:jar:2.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.240s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 30 22:23:24 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/325M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project JIRAService: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.group:my:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.google.code.guice:guice:jar:2.0 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCeRT.png
```

The dependency added

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.guice-repository/guice-repository -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.guice-repository</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice-repository</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You aded 2.0.1 not 2.0 ?!

Comment: Still not working

Comment: I just checked the Maven repository, the plugin IS there. So I suspect you have a proxy issue or something. Do other dependencies download succesfully? Are you behind a proxy, do you have internet connection?

Comment: No issues with other dependencies.

Comment: What I find unusual is 0 usages for the dependency in maven repository.

Comment: Can you try renaming your repository and trying again? Then see if you have the same error.

Comment: i deleted the cached contents.still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Removed the dependency for com.google.code.guice:guice:jar:2.0 from my project solved the issue.

I think the mvn dependency is not functional and hence was not able to download it.